# How to get a warning from Firefox before you close when downloads are in progress?

Tags: firefox, download

I sometimes close Firefox while I have downloads in progress that do not support resuming. Then when I open Firefox again I have to go to the original download location and start from scratch. It would be useful if there was a way to get a warning from Firefox before I close the application when downloads are in progress. Anyone know of a way to configure it to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Try to set the value of `browser.download.manager.quitBehavior` at Firefox `about:config`. It can be set to [these](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.download.manager.quitBehavior) values. To get a warining you should set it to 2.

Source: [support.mozilla.com](http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=fi&comments_parentId=217909&forumId=1#threadId245931)

Comment: Comment by @Precaq: Just for the record and non-english folks - it's not "Bahvior" but "Behavior" so the value should be browser.download.manager.quitBehavior...

Comment: Sharp @Precaq! I edited it for you :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201/) addon and even if I close Firefox, the download window remains open as a separate window. This prevents me from stopping my unresumable downloads accidentally.

Comment: +1 nice, didn´t know about that addon. going to try it ;-) thanks

Comment: I've been using it for a long time and I'm quite satisfied. It has nice features. Trust me, you won't regret ;)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Does it??? It just talking abt the addon which don't fix the question/problem.

Comment: @Millisami: Using this addon fixes the problem. Even if you close Firefox, the DTA download window remains open as a separate window. Got it?

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider to set `browser.warnOnQuit` and `browser.showQuitWarning` in Firefox's `about:config` to `true` to get a warning when closing the browser, not only when a download is in progress. This might save you some headaches when you accidentially try to close Firefox and were typing text into some input boxes for example. See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.warnOnQuit.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `browser.download.manager.quitBehavior` doesn't exist anymore; it has been removed in recent FF versions.

One (slightly clunky) workaround is to go to `Downloads` -> `Show all downloads` when you're downloading something big you may forget about. It will show a new download window, independent from FF. But you have to remember beforehand.

The missing preference is just screaming for a bug report, though.