# Does closing Firefox cancel / stop downloads?

Tags: firefox, download

Well, this question might have been asked (and answered) before, but I haven't found any good (and current) information besides [this](https://superuser.com/q/193589/228536) 3-year old post, that explains a way to allow Firefox to warn before closing if a download is being made.

To sum up: **Does closing Firefox completely (i.e. closing all windows, no** `firefox.exe` **process remaining) stop or cancel an active download? And an upload (such as one made to Dropbox)?**

I'm not specific about the OS used as I am assuming the behavior is identical to all OS Firefox has been ported.

If so, and besides having a download manager (like DownThemAll) or the good old download UI (accessible through `about:config > browser.download.useToolkitUI = True`, that is the same as having an active Firefox process) is there a way to download / upload without worrying I might accidentally close Firefox?

Comment: If you close the process Firefox cannot download or continue to download a file.  Using a download manager will use that process to download a file.  Most are a scam of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: Yes, it stops/halts any active downloads/uploads. If the process is killed, then there is no program activity whatsoever.

You can use [MinimizeToTray](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/minimizetotray-revived/) extension/addon to send firefox to tray. You can also set it to send firefox to tray instead of closing it ("Minimize To Tray Behavior & Click Behavior" in the addon preferences). See this post too: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/5771/minimize-firefox-to-the-system-tray-the-easy-way/